# HTTP header ETag not sent back to server

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, browser-cache, etag

I'm providing an ETag in the Response Header from the server to the browser when supplying a javascript file generated programatically.
On subsequent requests for that same javascript file the ***ETag does not get supplied back in Request Header*** by the browser.

I've tried this in both Chrome and IE, same results find below the request and response headers from original request and subsequent one.

**Original Request Header**

```
GET /v11/RUNTIME_SUPPORT.GetGlobalFormResources.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: 101.152.80.163
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: */*
X-FirePHP-Version: 0.0.6
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.66 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://101.152.80.163/v11/Web_Support.Html.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ro;q=0.6,es;q=0.4
Cookie: StaraspxOpenTabsCount=0; ASP.NET_SessionId=jpdkfccaf0zttoxyvys53ac3; STARaspx_SessionId=1006606D-F415-4AE5-AA4C-847625EB2BAE
If-None-Match: 0.0.459
```

**Original Response Header**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=604800
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
ETag: 0.0.459,0.0.0,0.00
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
ItemType: FORMS
Digest: e0d3a2bdee4c0a48bc4f61bb744755c21c1d6c19
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: callfrom, content-type, runtimecalltype
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2016 11:46:06 GMT
Content-Length: 31763
```

**Subsequent Request Header**

```
GET /v11/RUNTIME_SUPPORT.GetGlobalFormResources.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: 101.152.80.163
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: */*
X-FirePHP-Version: 0.0.6
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.66 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://101.152.80.163/v11/Web_Support.Html.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ro;q=0.6,es;q=0.4
Cookie: StaraspxOpenTabsCount=0; ASP.NET_SessionId=jpdkfccaf0zttoxyvys53ac3; STARaspx_SessionId=1006606D-F415-4AE5-AA4C-847625EB2BAE
If-None-Match: 0.0.459
```

**Subsequent Response Header**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=604800
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
ETag: 0.0.459,0.0.0,0.00
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
ItemType: FORMS
Digest: e0d3a2bdee4c0a48bc4f61bb744755c21c1d6c19
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: callfrom, content-type, runtimecalltype
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2016 11:46:48 GMT
Content-Length: 31763
```

Answer (score 1):

I've identified the **root causes for ETags not working in my scenario**:

- I should have looked at the ***If-None-Match request header field*** rather than expecting an ETag field be provided to the server (more details here [Header Field Definitions](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html))
- I should have ***not used commas in my ETag respose header field value***, only the sub-string before the first comma gets sent back in request header field If-None-Match. In my case the ETag value in respose header was `0.0.459,0.0.0,0.00` and the subsequent request had `0.0.459` in the If-None-Match header field.

Response header from server now: `HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified` :)